# ElasticSearch SearchRequest not returning must match on first element in the document

Tags: java, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7, resthighlevelclient

I have the following documents inserted in an ElasticSearch domain.

```
{"depID:": "5656", "employeeID": "7777", "jobID": "2345"}
{"depID:": "6767", "employeeID": "9999", "jobID": "2345"}
{"depID:": "7676", "employeeID": "8888", "jobID": "2345"}
```

When I perform a SearchRequest on depID, I get 0 hits. But when I perform it on employeeIDs or jobIDs I'm getting the correct hits in response. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Below is how I'm creating these documents.

```
public IndexResponse indexDocumentRequest(final String indexName, final String jsonDocument) throws IOException {
    IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest(indexName);
    indexRequest.source(jsonDocument, XContentType.JSON);
    return restHighLevelClient.index(indexRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
}

IndexResponse indexResponse =
            esDao.indexDocumentRequest("employees", "{\"depID:\": \"5656\", \"employeeID\": \"7777\", \"jobID\": \"2345\"}");
```

Below is the method in which I'm running the SearchRequests.

```
public SearchResponse searchDocumentRequest(final String indexName, final String jsonDocument) throws IOException {
        QueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.wrapperQuery(jsonDocument);
        SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
        searchSourceBuilder.query(queryBuilder);
        SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
        searchRequest.indices(indexName);
        searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
        return restHighLevelClient.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
    }
```

Below is how I'm calling the above Search method.

```
 SearchResponse searchResponse = esDao.searchDocumentRequest("employees",
            "{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"match\":{\"depID\":\"5656\"}}]}}");
 SearchResponse searchResponse = esDao.searchDocumentRequest("employees",
            "{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"match\":{\"depID\":\"6767\"}}]}}");
```

None of the above calls return any hits! But the below calls on other fields return the correct hits.

```
SearchResponse searchResponse = esDao.searchDocumentRequest("employees",
            "{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"match\":{\"employeeID\":\"7777\"}}]}}");
SearchResponse searchResponse = esDao.searchDocumentRequest("employees",
            "{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"match\":{\"jobID\":\"2345\"}}]}}");
```

What am I doing wrong here? Why won't the depID searches not return any hits? Any advice would be much appreciated

UPDATE:
The index mapping I have for the documents seem to be as follows.

```
{
  "properties": {
    "jobID": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "ignore_above": 256,
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    },
    "depID:": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "ignore_above": 256,
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    },
    "employeeID": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "ignore_above": 256,
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you share your index mapping that is created when you inserted the data?
That may help in understanding the query results in both scenarios.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-mapping.html

Update:

The issue is with the field name, There is a `:` missing in the depID in the query.

Comment: Sure, this is what I'm getting when I fetch the index mapping.
{ "properties": { "jobID": { "type": "text", "fields": { "keyword": { "ignore_above": 256, "type": "keyword" } } }, "depID:": { "type": "text", "fields": { "keyword": { "ignore_above": 256, "type": "keyword" } } }, "employeeID": { "type": "text", "fields": { "keyword": { "ignore_above": 256, "type": "keyword" } } } } }

Comment: I tried using your documents and figured out the issue. It is in the document you are indexing. It is not depID, it is depID: with a ':' at the end. 
So your query should be  
`SearchResponse searchResponse = esDao.searchDocumentRequest("employees", "{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"match\":{\"depID:\":\"5656\"}}]}}");`

Comment: A silly mistake it is. Can you update the answer with this? I'll accept it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

You are indexing the documents using the `indexDocumentRequest` method, in the **`employees`** index and you are running search requests using the `searchDocumentRequest2` method, in the **`candidates`** index.

Since both the index are different, maybe due to this, you are not getting accurate search results.

Comment: Sorry that was a paste mistake, I edited the question with the correct index